# How can I mock a private property in a class I'm trying to test in jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a class method I want to test:

```
setStepResolution(resolution: stepResolution): void {
        switch (resolution) {
            case stepResolution.FULL_SETUP:
                this.stepperMotors.left.ms1Pin.digitalWrite(0)
                this.stepperMotors.left.ms2Pin.digitalWrite(0)
                this.stepperMotors.left.ms3Pin.digitalWrite(1)
                this.stepperMotors.right.ms1Pin.digitalWrite(0)
                this.stepperMotors.right.ms2Pin.digitalWrite(0)
                this.stepperMotors.right.ms3Pin.digitalWrite(1)
                break
            case stepResolution.HALF_STEP:
                this.stepperMotors.left.ms1Pin.digitalWrite(1)
                this.stepperMotors.left.ms2Pin.digitalWrite(0)
                this.stepperMotors.left.ms3Pin.digitalWrite(0)
                this.stepperMotors.right.ms1Pin.digitalWrite(1)
                this.stepperMotors.right.ms2Pin.digitalWrite(0)
                this.stepperMotors.right.ms3Pin.digitalWrite(0)
                break
```

Each of these `digitalWrite` calls is made to an instance of a different class that are created when my class is constructed:

```
export default class BotController {

    private stepperMotors: StepperMotorCollection

    constructor() {
        this.initalizeMotors()
    }

    private initalizeMotors(): void {
        this.stepperMotors = {
            left: {
                directionPin: new Gpio(Number(process.env.LEFT_DIRECTION_PIN), { mode: Gpio.OUTPUT }),
                stepPin: new Gpio(Number(process.env.LEFT_STEP_PIN), { mode: Gpio.OUTPUT }),
                ms1Pin: new Gpio(Number(process.env.LEFT_RESOLUTION_PIN_MS1), { mode: Gpio.OUTPUT }),
                ms2Pin: new Gpio(Number(process.env.LEFT_RESOLUTION_PIN_MS2), { mode: Gpio.OUTPUT }),
                ms3Pin: new Gpio(Number(process.env.LEFT_RESOLUTION_PIN_MS3), { mode: Gpio.OUTPUT }),
                stepsPerMM: Number(process.env.LEFT_STEPS_PER_MM),
                swapCoils: Boolean(process.env.LEFT_SWAP_COILS),
            },
            right: {
                directionPin: new Gpio(Number(process.env.RIGHT_DIRECTION_PIN), { mode: Gpio.OUTPUT }),
                stepPin: new Gpio(Number(process.env.RIGHT_STEP_PIN), { mode: Gpio.OUTPUT }),
                ms1Pin: new Gpio(Number(process.env.RIGHT_RESOLUTION_PIN_MS1), { mode: Gpio.OUTPUT }),
                ms2Pin: new Gpio(Number(process.env.RIGHT_RESOLUTION_PIN_MS2), { mode: Gpio.OUTPUT }),
                ms3Pin: new Gpio(Number(process.env.RIGHT_RESOLUTION_PIN_MS3), { mode: Gpio.OUTPUT }),
                stepsPerMM: Number(process.env.RIGHT_STEPS_PER_MM),
                swapCoils: Boolean(process.env.RIGHT_SWAP_COILS),
            },
        }
    }
```

I could create a mock for the `stepperMotors` property in my test with mocks of the `Gpio` class (I'm already mocking the constructor for some of the other tests):

```
test("can change step resolution", () => {
        // * The step resolution of the stepper motors can be changed via the code.
        // * The settings can be controlled by an enum that denotes each of the possible
        // * resolutions.

        const mockStepperMotorConfiguration: StepperMotorCollection = {
            left: {
                directionPin: new pigpio.Gpio(1),
                stepPin: new pigpio.Gpio(1),
                ms1Pin: new pigpio.Gpio(1),
                ms2Pin: new pigpio.Gpio(1),
                ms3Pin: new pigpio.Gpio(1),
                stepsPerMM: 1,
                swapCoils: false,
            },
            right: {
                directionPin: new pigpio.Gpio(1),
                stepPin: new pigpio.Gpio(1),
                ms1Pin: new pigpio.Gpio(1),
                ms2Pin: new pigpio.Gpio(1),
                ms3Pin: new pigpio.Gpio(1),
                stepsPerMM: 1,
                swapCoils: false,
            },
        }

        // ^ To change the resolution to a full step
        // * send in the full step enum
        newController.setStepResolution(stepResolution.FULL_SETUP)
```

But I can't because the `stepperMotor` property is private.

There are several ways I could solve this (make the property public, make a public method for setting the property), but neither of them seems desirable because the property should never be accessible outside of the class so I would be exposing properties or methods only to support testing.

Is there another way of doing this kind of test? I know in jest I can mock a method on a class in javascript by replacing the prototype function e.g.:

```
BotController.prototype.someMethod = jest.fn()
const controller = new BotController
```

And if this was a class I was trying to mock I could pass in the properties as a mock implementation, e.g.:

```
jest.mock("../BotController", () => ({
    stepperMotors: mockStepperMotorConfiguration
}))
```

But then everything else in the class would also be mocked and you'd loose the point.

Any idea on how I should approach this?

## Update: trying to create a backdoor

I'm trying out Taplar's approach of creating a backdoor.

I tried casting my controller instance as an `any`:

[image: making a backdoor]

But the complier is still yelling at me:

[image: blergh]

## Another update

After Taplar pointed out how to call the method on the cast version the errors went away on the back door which is fantastic!

The next wall I smashed into was that now for some reason the test can't see my mock anymore which is weird because the variable is local to the test.

[image: closer]

Comment: Does jest have the ability to mock methods with fake methods?  Or even if it doesn't, you could try to replace a method on the class instance (or add one) that then tries to change the `this.stepperMotors`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wLs3jhzn/ <= dummy example not using any possibly existing jest methods.

Comment: oh man, I love that approach, that's super cleaver! Sadly it doesn't work because I'm using typescript. I tried that and the compiler errored out because the backdoor property doesn't already exist on the class :| with that approach I tried replacing the `initalizeMotors` method on the prototype too and the compiler failed on that too because the method is also private.

Comment: `(yourInstance as any).backdoor = ...` <= you can cast the instance as any to tell typescript to shut up.

Comment: Hmm, tried the cast but the compiler is still complaining :| I _love_ having the typescript compiler there for most things, but it's very frustrating here

Comment: Also `(controller as any).backdoor()` to invoke it.  In general, if typescript says you can't do something, typing it temporarily as `any` will make typescript more accepting, :)

Comment: And if you don't like repeating that casting over and over; `const temp = controller as any;` and then use temp instead.

Comment: Oh nice! that worked for calling the back door, but now when I try to fire `expect(mockStepperMotorConfiguration.left.ms1Pin.digitalWrite).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1)` I get the error `Cannot find name 'mockStepperMotorConfiguration'.ts` which is really weird because it's a variable local to the test function. hmm

Comment: Blergh, I pivoted & added a public method (even though I don't want to) to see if that approach would work and it does, though it raised a different question on how to test a sequence of calls in jest. I made a new question for that one because it feels like a different topic & I don't want to muddy this one up. I'd like to figure out the test with this backdoor or some other keep-everything-private approach, but if that doesn't work hopefully I'll be able to pivot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63588319/how-to-test-a-specific-sequence-of-calls-to-the-same-function-with-jest

Comment: `backdoor` is a total overkill here. `(yourInstance as any)` is applicable to any place where type checks need to be ignored, primarily `stepperMotors`. As for mockStepperMotorConfiguration, you didn't post the whole code but it appears that you have mismatched `)` and it breaks the syntax.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Unless [`#` hard privacy](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-8-beta/#ecmascript-private-fields) is used, private properties can be accessed outside a class at runtime, TypeScript access modifiers are applied only at compilation time.

Accessing private members in tests can be considered a reflection.

Visibility can be bypassed with bracket notation, which is the preferable option:

```
controllerInstance['stepperMotors'] = ...;
```

Or with Reflect API:

```
Reflect.set(controllerInstance, 'stepperMotors', ...);
```

Or by disabling type checks:

```
(controllerInstance as any).stepperMotors = ...;
```

Since private property is set with prototype method, another approach is to mock it. It's applicable if original initialization causes undesirable side effects and needs to be avoided. `BotController.prototype.someMethod = jest.fn()` should never be used in Jest as it cannot be automatically cleaned up and cross-contaminates tests. Instead it could be:

```
jest.spyOn(BotController.prototype, 'initalizeMotors').mockImplementation(function (this: BotController) {
  this['stepperMotors'] = ...;
});
...
expect(controllerInstance['initalizeMotors']).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: :facepalm: jeez I didn't even think to try bracket notation! After reading this I realized that I read about doing that when es6 classes were first introduced and later forgot about it. 

I didn't know about the Reflect class though, that's a really good to know!

Thanks for laying out all of these options. It's great to have examples of these approaches :bows:

Comment: any update on how this would be possible for the `#` hard privacy methods?