# How to test a specific sequence of calls to the same function with jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a class I'm trying to test that makes a sequence of calls to a mock function in jest:

[image: the calls I want to test]

I have a mock for the `Gpio` class constructor that creates the object instances behind these properties. The mock class has a mock method for `digitalWrite`:

[image: mock class]

And when I run my test I can see the sequence of calls made to digitalWrite:

[image: the sequence]

But I can't figure out how to test that the sequence is correct. I feel like if I can see the sequence in the test fail hint I should be able to say "call first with a 0, then with a 0, then with a 1", but I can't quite figure out how to do it. Any ideas?

Also so that it doesn't get pointed out: I know that technically each of the pin instances should be separate and I should be able to test them individually, but with the way you mock constructors in jest I have to use the same mock function for `digitalWrite`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jest's [.toHaveBeenNthCalledWith()](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavebeennthcalledwithnthcall-arg1-arg2-)

e.g.

```
it('should be called in the following sequence', () => {
  expect(......digitalWrite).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, 0)
  expect(......digitalWrite).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(2, 0)
  expect(......digitalWrite).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(3, 1)
})
```

or you can use the mock function's [mock.calls](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockcalls) property:

```
it('should be called in the following sequence', () => {
  expect(......digitalWrite).toHaveProperty('mock.calls', [
    [0], [0], [1]
  ])
})
```

Comment: Oh nice!! Yeah that works perfectly. Good to know about the second option, it seems like that will make this test more readable. Thanks!!