# Testing Private Properties on a Class Instance [TypeScript]

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have a class with a constructor.

```
export default class S3Client {
  private readonly s3: S3;
  private readonly bucketName: string;
  private readonly useS3Data: boolean;

  constructor(configuration: IConfig = config, region: string = 'eu-west-1') {
    this.bucketName = configuration.bucketName;
    this.s3 = new S3({ region });
    this.useS3Data = [ 'int', 'test', 'live' ].includes(configuration.env);
  }
...
}
```

This was written manually and not by the IDE so it needs testing (besides the code coverage checker isn't happy without these tests).

Yes, they're tested indirectly though testing methods on this class, but how do I test the properties are as expected directly?

```
describe('constructor', () => {
  // mock setup stuff here
  test('as expected', () => {
    const clientUnderTest = new S3Client(mockEnvValueObjPassedIn);
    expect(clientUnderTest.bucketName).toEqual('test-bucket-name');
  });
});
```

``
This obviously doesn't work because the `bucketName` is private.
I have tried having another prototype of the `clientUnderTest` with `Object.getPrototypeOf(clientUnderTest);` but because of the complicated way prototypes work it only produces an empty object, but does seem to know about the properties with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(clientUnderTest)`.
I've tried copying the object since I can console log a stringified version of my `clientUnderTest` with `Object.assign({}, underTest);` but I get exactly the same errors regarding the privacy of the attributes. How do I get around this please?

I AM NOT INTERESTED IN

- making a getter
- making these values public
- making them protected then making an accessible subclass
- any other hack where I have to compromise my code just to satisfy a test.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63587868/how-can-i-mock-a-private-property-in-a-class-im-trying-to-test-in-jest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `const a = new S3Client`, `a['bucketName']` works, and it's what I went with in the end.